# Cannot get rspec controller tests to see my sessions controller override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rspec3

I was trying to write a test that broke and fell down a rabbit hole of trying to get rspec to even see my override. I intentionally am raise an error so that I will notice it. This code successfully raises an error in development mode when I run `rails server`.

```
class Devise::Extends::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :log_logout, only: :destroy
  after_filter :log_failed_login, only: [:new, :create]

  def create
    raise 'create'
    super do |user|
      # special stuff to go here
    end
  end
end
```

I'm setting the `devise.mapping` and have tried it with and without the `@`.

```
describe LicenseesController do
  context 'viewing existing Licensee' do
    let(:other_licensee) { FactoryGirl.create(:licensee) }
    context 'as licensee_user for Licensee' do
      # For own Licensee
      #   allows show
      #   disallows index, new, edit, create, delete, update
      # For another Licensee
      #   returns not authorized
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:licensee_user, :confirmed) }

      before(:each) do
        @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]

        sign_in user
      end
      describe "GET show" do
        it "assigns the requested licensee as @licensee" do
          get :show, {:id => user.licensee.to_param}, valid_session
          assigns(:licensee).should eq(user.licensee)
        end

        it "rejects trying to show another Licensee" do
          expect do
            get :show, {:id => other_licensee.to_param}, valid_session
          end.to raise_exception(CanCan::AccessDenied)
        end
     end
     # more tests  


  # This should return the minimal set of attributes required to create a valid
  # Licensee. As you add validations to Licensee, be sure to
  # adjust the attributes here as well.
  let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:licensee) }
  let(:wsu_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:web_service_user) }

  # This should return the minimal set of values that should be in the session
  # in order to pass any filters (e.g. authentication) defined in
  # LicenseesController. Be sure to keep this updated too.
  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  context 'as superuser' do
    before(:each) { sign_in user }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:superuser, :confirmed) }
    describe "GET index" do
      it "assigns all licensees as @licensees" do
        licensee = Licensee.create! valid_attributes
        get :index, {}, valid_session
        assigns(:licensees).should eq([licensee])
      end
    end


  end
```

And in my `routes.rb` I have:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'devise/extends/sessions' }
```

Am I missing something obvious that's required to get this to work? It raises an error as expected via `cucumber` tests and interactively, but the `rspec` tests seem to completely skip the override and all of the tests pass.

Comment: Umm, where's your actual test code?

Comment: Sorry. Trimmed too early.

Comment: So your rspec tests are all green?

Comment: Yes. All rspecs are green. Was actually even doing devise.mapping setting in spec_helper, but decided to isolated down to a single spec.

Comment: Well then looks like everything is working. Your test expects your show action to raise_exception(CanCan::AccessDenied) And indeed - since your tests are green - it is raising that error. Meaning your show action never runs because the CanCan before_filter is raising the AccessDenied error.

Comment: Added the index example. I'm testing multiple actions and success and failure and all pass.

Comment: Ok, so they all pass. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the `:create` method isn't getting called. I have an intentional raise there to verify. I'm using Devise::TestHelpers, so I know that's not the problem.